# Connect Hive with keytab using python

Tags: python, hive, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, keytab

I am looking for an option to connect Hive with keytab using python. Tried the option Jaydebeapi to establish the connection, but no success yet

```
import jaydebeapi

DIR = root_path
jarFile = [ DIR + 'hive-jdbc-2.3.7.jar',
        DIR + 'commons-logging-1.2.jar',
        DIR + 'hive-service-3.1.1.jar',
        DIR + 'hive-service-rpc-3.1.1.jar',
        DIR + 'libthrift-0.12.0.jar',
        DIR + 'httpclient-4.5.9.jar',
        DIR + 'httpcore-4.4.11.jar',
        DIR + 'slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar',
        DIR + 'curator-framework-4.2.0.jar',
        DIR + 'curator-recipes-4.2.0.jar',
        DIR + 'curator-client-4.2.0.jar',
        DIR + 'commons-lang-2.6.jar',
        DIR + 'hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar',
        DIR + 'httpcore-4.4.11.jar',
        DIR + 'hive-common-3.1.1.jar',
        DIR + 'hive-serde-3.1.1.jar',
        DIR + 'guava-28.0-jre.jar',
        DIR + 'zookeeper-3.4.6.jar',
        DIR + 'hive-shims-common-2.1.0.jar']

   dirver = 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver' 

  # JDBC connection string
  url=["jdbc:hive2://' +server_with_port 
  +'/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/_HOST@_REALM;"]

 #Connect to HiveServer2
 conn=jaydebeapi.connect(dirver, url, jars=jarFile)
```

When I run this code, i get the error as below
`return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs) RuntimeError: No matching overloads found for getConnection in find. at native\common\jp_method.cpp:127`

Tried the option pyHive, but sasl installation fails in windows and not able to proceed with that. And moreover I am not sure if there is a possibility to use keytab file in pyHive.

Please suggest any better solution if you have.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by _"using keytab file"_?? A keytab contains an encrypted password to authenticate against a Kerberos KDC, either via `kinit` command line (to obtain a Kerberos ticket and store it in the user cache, so that other programs may use it) or via Java JAAS config (to obtain a Kerberos ticket and keep it private in the Java program). I see nothing of that kind in your code.

Comment: Thank you Samson for your response. 
What I meant here is, using kinitad I created my key tab file and is available to use. Since the hive that I’m trying to connect than be accessed with the key tab file. I’m looking for a provision to provide this file in the connection string. 

You are absolutely right, that in my current code I don’t have any option to provide and that’s what I’m looking for. 

What I have currently is the server details, database and table details and a valid .keytab file and looking for a python solution to run the query.

Comment: You clearly don't understand what you are doing. So start simple: **1.** `kinit -kt <keytab> <principal-of-Kerberos-user>`  **2.** `python`  **3.** `import impyla` **4.** read the Impyla docs -- that lib is maintained by Cloudera, it is supposed to work in most configurations (except maybe with Knox gateway)

Comment: Sure, i will try your suggested option.